# Could not load an entity in NHibernate then Timeout Exception when Table is existing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need help on this.

I got this error while inserting/updating a number of records

```
could not load an entity: 
[Star.CNPL_BusinessObjects.Entities.CNPL.CNPL_AgencyProduct#48][SQL: SELECT cnpl_agenc0_.Id as Id48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.AgencyID as AgencyID48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.ProductID as ProductID48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.CreatedDate as CreatedD4_48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.UpdatedDate as UpdatedD6_48_0_, cnpl_agenc0_.UpdatedBy as UpdatedBy48_0_ FROM CNPL_AgencyProduct cnpl_agenc0_ WHERE cnpl_agenc0_.Id=?]"
```

Then, I get this inner exception

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader() 
   at NHibernate.Impl.BatcherImpl.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) 
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) 
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) 
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) 
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, Type optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
```

Need help on this guys. Ideas can help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the solution to the issue.

It seems that NHibernate is having a hard time when it changes from update to insert. The problem is that when there's an insert before an update in bulk transactions, this error happens. What we did was we separated the update and the insert transactions and it worked.

I'm wondering if this is because of the NHibernate dll. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below statements before execute the nhiberbate: as example:

```
if (_session.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _session.Connection.Close();
                    _session.Connection.Open();
                }
                else if (_session.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {                    
                    _session.Connection.Open();
                }

result = _session.CreateCriteria<T>().List<T>();
```